# About tf.keras SGD batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sgd

I want to use SGD optimizer in tf.keras.
But SGD detail said

> Gradient descent (with momentum) optimizer.

Dose it mean SGD doesn't support "Randomly shuffle examples in the data set phase"?
I checked the SGD [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py#L30-L194),
It seems that there is no random shuffle method.
My understanding about SGD is applying gradient descent for random sample.
But it does only gradient descent with momentum and nesterov.

Does the batch-size which I defined in code represent SGD random shuffle phase?
If so, it does randomly shuffle but never use same dataset, doesn't it?
Is my understanding correct?

I wrote code about batch as below.

```
    (x_train, y_train)).shuffle(10000).batch(32)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(32)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand. However, whether or not (and how) you shuffle your data is completely independent from the optimizer in frameworks like keras.

Comment: @xdurch0 I wrote code about batch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for, but try using the tf.data.Dataset for your Dataset. For example, for mnist you can easily create the dataset variable, shuffle the samples and divide in batches:

```
shuffle_buffer_size = 100
batch_size = 10
train, test = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
images, labels = train
images = images/255
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, labels))
dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size).batch(batch_size)
```

You can have a look at the tutorial about datasets: [td.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)